# Laravel can't detect last / from url

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

We're trying to remove last / from url to avoid google duplicate contents. I created a middleware for 301 redirect.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class NonSlashURL
{

    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {

        if (substr($request->fullUrl(), -1) == '/') {
            $trimmedURL = rtrim($request->fullUrl(), "/");
            return redirect($trimmedURL, 301);
        } else {
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve if user enter https://test.com/content/, that middleware redirect user to https://test.com/content

But if I get full url;

```
dd($request->fullUrl());
```

It gives me https://test.com/content even I enter website with https://test.com/content/.

Comment: Have you tried htaccess?

Comment: Generally this sort of redirect is best added to your webserver configuration for apache (as @sta mentioned) you can specify such a rule in .htaccess and for nginx you can have a similar rule in your nginx.conf . It's better this way because the redirect happens before any PHP code runs so is less resource intensive

Answer (score 0):

laravel string helpers help you for implement that easily:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;


class NonSlashURL
{

    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {

        $url=$request->fullUrl();
        if (Str::endsWith($url,'/')) {
            $trimmedURL = Str::beforeLast($url, '/');
            return redirect($trimmedURL, 301);
        } else {
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
}
```